# Float on change

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have icon, which on click adds new div's (columns) to div container. The problem is that when new div's (columns) appears the button doesn't shift right. Is it possible to somehow add `position:fixed` only inside the div?

Here is a few screens of what I have

[image]

[image]

And some code

```
    <div id="grid">
        <div id="add-col"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="squares"></div>
    </div>


#grid{
    width:710px; 
    height: 470px;
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: auto;
}

#add-col{
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
    background-image: url(images/table-add-column-icon.png);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be on 1 position all the time even when you scroll or 1 default position or does it need to move?

Comment: @Ladineko i need that this icon would always be in the corner of parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS would look like this :

```
#grid{
    width:710px; 
    height: 470px;
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: auto;

    position:relative; //added

}

#add-col{
    margin:5px;

    background-image: url(images/table-add-column-icon.png);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;

    position:absolute; //added
    top:5px; //added
    right:5px; //added

}
```

With position `absolute` you can place a button in a corner without having it to move from that position ever again.

To use a position you need to place `position:relative;` to its parent, else it will fly around the page.

**Note:** `float` has been deleted from #add-col

Comment: same sheet, but with one difference - now icons is on the square, because it's position is absolute

Comment: you can give the other icons the position:absolute aswell but with different values in top and right. In top and right you just give it the position it needs to be.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that when i add new divs the icons stays in the same place, and when i scrolling to right it disappears.

Comment: So you want to scroll the page and during the scroll it sticks in the same position? then you need to use Fixed instead of Absolute.

Comment: yes, but it fixes on all scrollings, but as i said in the question `May be possible somehow add position:fixed only inside the div?`

Comment: can you provide a sample in jsFiddle and show me what you want to achieve if this isnt is what your looking for